Transformations from $s$ to $z$: what can we gain from higher-order mappings?
Transforming continuous-time (CT) filters to the discrete domain is frequently done via the bilinear transform:
$$s=\frac{2}{T}\frac{z-1}{z+1}\tag{1}$$
The constant $2/T$ in $(1)$ can be replaced by some other constant to guarantee the equivalence of the CT transfer function and the discrete-time (DT) transfer function at a specified frequency ("pre-warping").
In the control engineering community, the bilinear transform is also referred to as Tustin's method. It is also equivalent to the trapezoidal rule of integration applied to differential equations.
The bilinear transform has many desirable properties and it gives useful results for a variety of practical applications. However, the approximation of the CT transfer function via the bilinear transform is sometimes far from ideal, and for some applications it could be interesting to use other mappings that are more accurate than $(1)$.
The "ideal" mapping between $s$ and $z$ is given by
$$z=e^{sT}\Longleftrightarrow sT=\ln (z)\tag{2}$$
Since we want to transform a rational CT transfer function to a rational DT transfer function - only such transfer functions can be implemented with delays, adders and multipliers - we seek a rational approximation of $(2)$.
In the wikipedia article on the bilinear transform it is pointed out that Eq. $(1)$ is the first term of the following series for the natural logarithm:
$$\ln(z)=2\left[\frac{z-1}{z+1}+\frac13\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^3+\frac15\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^5+\ldots\right]\tag{3}$$
The question is: can we design DT filters based on CT filters using a higher-order mapping according to $(3)$ such that the approximation of the CT prototype filter is considerably better than the one obtained via the bilinear transform?

Long ago, in college, we fiddled with a mapping in which the mapping for $s^2$ was not the same as the square of the mapping for $s$.  Some IEEE paper.  We did a Butterworth LPF and the straight slope in the transition (I think it was -12 dB/oct) was straighter up to higher frequencies than the same filter mapped to discrete-time with the bilinear transform.

Here's an IEEE paper, but it can't be the one that we were referring to in my class when we tried other $z$ to $s$ mappings.  Because this paper is 1991 and the other one must be at least a dozen years earlier.  It's just that I cannot remember the mappings from my head.

There are tons of papers on the topic..  I have no friggin' idea what they say about it.

@robertbristow-johnson: Thanks for the pointers! They are mainly from people from the control theory community, didn't know any of them. Strange that there doesn't seem to be much from DSP people.

First of all, it's clear that a higher-order mapping increases the filter order of the DT filter compared to the original CT filter. So the possible improvement of the transfer function compared to the one obtained via the bilinear transform must be considerable to make it worth the additional implementation cost.
Second, in order to be able to assess what can be expected from using more terms in the series (Eq. $(3)$ in the question) it's good to know where this series comes from and what its limitations are. This series is derived from the Taylor series of the area hyperbolic tangent:
$$\operatorname{atanh}(t)=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2n+1}}{2n+1},\qquad |t|<1\tag{1}$$
With
$$z=\frac{1+t}{1-t}\tag{2}$$
we obtain from $(1)$
$$\ln(z)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^{2n+1}\tag{3}$$
However, convergence of the Taylor series $(1)$ is only attained for $|t|<1$, which, according to $(2)$, translates to $\textrm{Re}\{z\}>0$. Hence, the series $(3)$ only converges for $\textrm{Re}\{z\}>0$, i.e.,  only for frequencies smaller than half the Nyquist frequency. Consequently, even though adding more terms in $(3)$ will improve the approximation of the CT transfer function by the DT transfer function at low frequencies, we have no control over what happens at and above half the Nyquist frequency.
EXAMPLE:
I transformed second-order Butterworth lowpass and highpass filters using the series $(3)$. The figure below shows the results. The blue curves are the transfer functions of the CT prototype filters. The red curves are the transfer functions of the DT filters designed via the bilinear transform. The other curves were obtained by adding higher-order terms to the bilinear term in $(3)$. I added up to three terms which means that the other mappings contain third, fifth, and seventh powers of $(z-1)/(z+1)$.
The figures shows that higher-order mappings approximate the CT transfer function better for frequencies lower than half the Nyquist frequency, as expected. However, the behavior at higher frequencies is undesirable. Two of the higher-order mappings have several zeros on the unit circle, hence the DC value of the corresponding transfer functions occurs also at higher frequencies, which makes these filters useless in practice. One of the mappings (purple) results in useful filters, but they don't approximate the CT filter for frequencies above half the Nyquist frequency. I.e., they don't achieve the goal of closely approximating the CT filter either.

We can conclude that using higher-order terms of the series $(3)$ doesn't help in approximating a CT filter transfer function more closely, unless we do not care about what happens at frequencies higher than half the Nyquist frequency.
However, even though using more terms of the series $(3)$ doesn't appear to result in useful filters, we can try to find other higher-order mappings approximating $\ln(z)$ with a rational function. A natural candidate are Padé approximants. It can be shown that the mapping implemented by the bilinear transform is the first order Padé approximant of $\ln(z)/T$ about $z=1$. Higher-order Padé approximants can be computed using the Mathematica/WolframAlpha command
PadeApproximant[log(x),{x,1,{m,n}}]
where m and n are the orders of the numerator and denominator of the rational approximant, respectively.
In all examples I used m=n, i.e., the same polynomial order for numerators and denominators. I only used odd orders because the even order mappings map $s=0$ (DC) not only to $z=1$ (DC) but also to $z=-1$ (Nyquist), which is useless for lowpass and highpass filters. It wouldn't matter for bandpass or bandstop filters.
The figure below shows the results for the same second-order Butterworth lowpass and highpass filters. The blue curves show the transfer functions of the CT filters. For the lowpass filter, the higher-order mappings result in DT transfer functions that are virtually identical to the CT filter up to about $60$% of the Nyquist frequency. Towards the Nyquist frequency, the DT transfer functions deviate and converge to zero because $z=-1$ maps to $s=\infty$. Note that a real-valued mapping function cannot implement the ideal mapping at Nyquist: $s=\pm i\pi/T \Longleftrightarrow z=-1$.
For the highpass filter, the filters obtained from higher-order mappings are equally close to the CT filter. They only deviate from the desired response close to Nyquist, where they all converge to $1$ (for the same reason as in the lowpass case).

We can conclude that using Padé approximants as mapping functions results in useful filters that closely approximate the CT prototype filter. There is a predictable deviation close to and at Nyquist due to the nature of the mapping functions.
In sum, higher-order mappings of the type
$$H(z)=H_c(f(z))$$
can be useful if

a close approximation of the CT transfer function is desirable
we don't mind some deviation around Nyquist
the CT filter order is low (because the filter order is increased by the higher-order mapping)


Maybe MIM (Magnitude Invariance Method) and PIM (Phase Invariance Method) ? Base Matlab -code can be found from thesis by Prathamesh R. Vadhavkar . c2dn() does not work well for certain type filters like HPF w/o modification.

@JuhaP: Thanks for reminding me of MIM and for the link! In this question (and answer) I was more interested in what can be achieved by direct mappings from $s$ to $z$, i.e., $H(z)=H_c(f(z))$ with some mapping function $s=f(z)$.
